# How to access web app live inside docker in docker

Tags: linux, docker

It may sounds wired, but I have to create a web app, say a MEAN stack one, on docker in docker.

The app works fine, and if setup on the docker in the host, it will expose port 3000 to host and the host can access to it using x.x.x.x:3000. Yet since it lives in docker in docker, which I used dind in [this project](https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind), I'm unable to have access to it from host since the mid layer docker container doesn't forword the 3000 from its container to its host.

In the dind project it says something about the command which did talk about port expose:

```
docker run --privileged -d -p 4444 -e PORT=4444 dind
```

Yet it only serve with daemon and no other interactive command line so even docker pull becomes impossible, and tbh I'm not sure what it really does. Now I just use:

```
docker run --privileged -d -it -p 3000 dind
```

And it doesn't forward the second layer docker container to the outside host.

Any idea on this situation? I've tried Google a lot but haven't got any idea.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after researching... I have to admit I'm so green at docker and linux...

So docker container is still a VM, but it also has port forwarding function itself. The only problem is that, the container must hock a port that is actually used in host.

Docker in docker has no difference from just plain docker. So the host will act like a remote machine for the mid-layer docker. Therefore what the mid-layer docker should do is pretty much like how to expose its container to the remote machines, as the other post says [remote access to docker container](http://Remote%20access%20to%20webserver%20in%20docker%20container)
The weird thing is that, using another port (I chose 8442) as a intermediate port, the issue mysteriously solved. The docker command is like this:

```
docker run -p 3000:8442 -d dind
docker run -p 8442:3000-d app
```

And from the host, I can get access to the app using the dind container ip and port 3000.

The issue I encountered led me to more understanding on docker networking, especially this official doc [Container networking](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#container-networking), and dind really didn't do much on it.

Comment: Please share the answer.

Comment: @Michael sorry about that, incomplete answer. Although I couldn't understand the way I solved.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the docker help section:

`docker help run`

> --privileged=false         Give extended privileges to this container

From the [Docker Reference](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration):

> By default, Docker containers are "unprivileged" and cannot, for example, run a Docker daemon inside a Docker container. This is because by default a container is not allowed to access any devices, but a "privileged" container is given access to all devices

This allows you to run docker inside of docker.

> -p, --publish=[]           Publish a container's port to the host
>
> ```
>                      format: ip:hostPort:containerPort | ip::containerPort | hostPort:containerPort
>
>                      (use 'docker port' to see the actual mapping)
> ```

This is a fancy way to say, expose these ports on the host. So your docker container is going to expose port 4444 to your localhost

> -e, --env=[]               Set environment variables

This sets an environment variable in the docker container, for use by the docker environment, in your command, you are setting the environment variable PORT to 4444

Basically whatever you run inside your 'dind' container will be able to use that environment variable to use the exposed port, i.e. your web app should be running on port 4444

If you want to expose the 3000 port, you can use:

`docker run --privileged -d -p 3000:3000 -e PORT=3000 dind`

disclaimer: I have not used dind, but the basic docker concepts are there. Perhaps the app inside dind is smart enough to use the PORT environment variable to map your app's port 3000 to 4444, which is completely possible, but not sure how your setup is.

Comment: That's right. And it works perfectly if you just run it on a container on your host. But what dind does is just create a image (and later on containers) that you can run docker on it, therefore creating another docker on the docker you have on the host. Maybe I didn't make myself clear on the post. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: I am unsure what you mean - if you can hit it on the host, what is the issue then?

Comment: Alright, say the images for the app is local/app, if you just create the container on your host, using, say docker run -it -p 3000:3000 local/app, that's fine. And you can connect to the app doing IP:3000. Yet, what if you are asked to create a container that runs on a docker, on a docker (the docker in docker stuff), docker in docker means your host run a container A, install docker on A, and build image/create container on A. Now the app is on a container that runs on A, how would you get access to it on your, say browser, using ip:port?

Comment: you have to expose that port 3000 on both your app docker and the host docker, then your host can access it.

Comment: That's what I hoped for... Now I'm looking for port forwarding, maybe it will help

Comment: I showed you how to do this in my original answer - you just need to expose the ports on both containers.

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work. For the command    docker run --privileged -d -p 3000 -e PORT=3000 dind, it might work. But when you have the env PORT, the docker will not have any command line prompt and you can do nothing on the one you created. Since I need to do install on the mid layer docker to create the app, I need to have interactive command line. BTW, after expose the ports on both containers, which ip would you choose to get access to the app? Apparently the docker container ip running on the host doesn't work.    Thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you for your help, you are right, and I figured out my issue is that I should hook on a physical port of the host.